# Is there a golden pyramid?

Tags: geometry, golden-ratio

*Is there a golden pyramid?*

Or pyramides? Would they have some interesting properties (related to let's say packing, etc.)?

---

Golden rectangle is said to be the most aestheticaly pleasing among rectangles:

[image]

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545637/decomposable-families-of-shapes) mentions golden triangles:

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154220/golden-parallelepiped) mentions golden parallelepiped:

[image]

---

NOTE: Someone even used golden rectangle to construct this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.goldennumber.net/phi-pi-great-pyramid-egypt/